# iTextSharp v5 throwing exception

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-form

I have a PDF form template that I fill from your C# code with values, to be printed out.

Suddenly, my customer reports errors - when trying to print the PDF (from an ASP.NET page), they get:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName' to type
>   'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfIndirectReference'

When digging in my code, I discovered this error happens on this line of code here:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("MyPdfTemplateName.pdf");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);

// filling field values here.....

stamper.FormFlattening = true;  // **** EXCEPTION HERE *****
stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false; 
stamper.Close();
```

The funny thing is: this only happens with the "new" version 5.0 of iTextSharp - I went back to my previous version 4.1.2, and with the **exact same code, exact same PDF form**, it works flawlessly.....

Anyone have any idea or insight as to **why** the new v5 of iTextSharp behaves this way??

Comment: Are you getting this with all PDF forms that you use, or is it just a particular one?

Comment: @Paddy: some work - other don't

Comment: The iText support is a bit odd, but have you tried posting on their mailing list: https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/itext-questions

Comment: Do you really need to upgrade to the latest version of the library, or could you simply continue to use the preceding version which works? This only reminds me of an expression: "If it's not broken, don't fix it"! That is, indeed, if you don't particularly need what v5.0 offers.

Comment: @Will Marcouiller: since the upgrade to v5 didn't solve my other problem either, I'll probably go back. I'm just curious to know what "broke" between v4 and v5, and how to fix it, if I ever do need to go to v5 for some reason.

Comment: @marc_s - may be worth bearing in mind that the license terms have changed between v4 and v5 - may no longer be free to use, depending on your circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the source, Marc!  Step in and find out what's wrong.

You'll have to use [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) directly to download it from the [SourceForge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/develop)...  I use [tortiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) which integrates with Windows Explorer quite nicely.  Love it.

<strike>I'm surprised Paulo isn't offering a source download.  I'll ask him about it.</strike>

Turns out the non-dll-only zip contains... The Source.  Wow, who saw that coming?  So any way, step in, see what's up.

Comment: I looked at the source myself the other day.  There is Absolutely No Way that particular line of code is throwing that particular exception.  It's a setter that just sets a boolean value.